# Clean cache based on DependencyKey

Tags: .net, vb.net, caching

Based on a datetime value I insert values into the cache:

```
Dim Value1 As String = "value1"
Dim Value2 As String = "value2"
Dim Key1 As String = "Key" & New Date(2014, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0).ToString
Dim Key2 As String = "Key" & New Date(2014, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0).ToString
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(Key1, Value1)
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(Key2, Value2)
```

Is it possible to invalidate those cache items using another cache item as CacheDependency?

I tried the following, but this doesn't work:

```
Dim Keys As String() = New String(0) {}
Keys(0) = "OtherKey"
Dim MyDependency As New System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(Nothing, Keys)
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(Key1, Value1, MyDependency)
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(Key2, Value2, MyDependency)

'To clear all cache items:
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("OtherKey")
```

When I use this (without the remove statement), the items never can be found in the cache. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a CacheDependency for another cache key:

- The key you depend on (ie *OtherKey*) must be found in the cache (See [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308147/en-us)). Otherwise your items will not be found in the cache.
- You need to create a different CacheDependency instance per item. Otherwise you will get the error `An attempt was made to reference a CacheDependency object from more than one Cache entry` (See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244888/cachedependancy-for-multiple-cached-items))

So your code to insert the items would be something like this:

```
' Make sure OtherKey is found in the cache
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("OtherKey", "SomeValue")

' Add the items with a different CacheDependency instance per item
Dim Keys As String() = New String(0) {}
Keys(0) = "OtherKey"
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(Key1, Value1, New System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(Nothing, Keys))
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(Key2, Value2, New System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(Nothing, Keys))
```

- Please note that if you don´t add the cache item with key *OtherKey*, the dependent items will never be found.

Then when you remove OtherKey from the cache, the dependent items will be automatically removed. So this line would automatically remove both *Key1* and *Key2* from the cache:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("OtherKey")
```

Hope it helps!